# Force Facebook autoplay for embed

Tags: html, facebook, video, html5-video

For quite some time now, facebook videos have autoplay when you scroll down the page. But today I noticed that even videos embedded from youtube are played automatically.

Inspecting an youtube url with facebook debugger, I didn't see anything containing `autoplay`. The `og:video` only contains two arrays - one for html5 and one for flash - and none of them has `autoplay` property.

[image: URLs from og:video]

However, at the bottom of the page, the debugger states that it will use urls with `autoplay=1` paramether.

[image: URLs Facebook uses for embedding]

Does anyone know is this achieved ?

Comment: This is a feature we are currently testing with a limited video providers.

Comment: I see. Any chance to apply for participation in the program?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible at the moment.